# Faster way to read ~400.000 rows of data with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I am working on a real-time information retrieval system which performs large queries on a local SQL Server database with around 4.5 million rows.

Each query returns, on average, 400.000 rows and is parameterized, like the following example:

```
SELECT Id, Features, Edges, Cluster, Objects FROM db.Image 
WHERE Cluster = 16 
AND Features IS NOT NULL 
AND Objects IS NOT NULL
```

These are the times I am getting with my current approach:

```
Query time: 4.52361000 seconds
Query size: 394048 rows, 5 columns
```

While not necessarily unusable, it is expected that query sizes will grow quickly, and as such I need a more efficient way to read large amounts of rows into a DataFrame.

Currently, I'm using `pyodbc` for building a connecting to SQL Server and `pd.read_sql` to parse the query directly into a DataFrame which is then manipulated. I am looking at ways to improve the query times significantly while still allowing me to work with DataFrame operations after the data is fetched. So far, I have tried `dask` DataFrames, [connectorX](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x), as well as failed attempts at parallelizing the queries with `multithreading`, but to no avail.

How can one, relying on other solutions, multithreading, or even entirely different file formats, improve the time it takes to read this amount of data?

*Code Sample*

```
conn = connection() # I have a function that returns a connector
filter = 16
command = '''SELECT Id, Features, Edges, Cluster, Objects FROM Common.Image
WHERE Cluster = {} AND Features IS NOT NULL AND Objects IS NOT NULL'''.format(filter)
result = pd.read_sql(command, conn)
```

**EDIT**

Following @tadman's comment:

> Consider caching this if practical, like once you've fetched the data you could save it in a more compact form (Google Protobuf, Parquet, etc.) Reading in that way can be considerably faster, as you're usually just IO bound, not server/CPU bound.

I looked at Parquet caching and landed on a considerably faster way to fetch my data:

1. Created compressed `parquet` files for each of my data clustes (1 to 21).
2. Using `pyarrow`, read the necessary cluster file with
   `df_pq = pq.read_table("\\cluster16.parquet")`
3. Convert the parquet file to a pandas DataFrame with `df = df_pq.to_pandas()`
4. Proceed as usual

With this method, I reduced the total time to `1.12400` seconds.

Comment: PSA: **DO NOT** use `format` to compose SQL queries. Use the proper [escaping method](https://bobby-tables.com/python), typically with placeholder values.

Comment: How much data does this represent? Are you fetching the same rows repeatedly? Could you make a `VIEW` that's leaner and quicker to fetch, that could be materialized for ease of access?

Comment: @tadman I was not aware of this, thank you! I've since used the `params` parameter from `pd.read_sql`.

Comment: @tadman I have a total of 21 clusters with similar sizes (~200-300k rows). Each query is responsible for fetching all the data I need about each cluster. I will attempt creating a `VIEW` and report back.

Comment: Consider caching this if practical, like once you've fetched the data you could save it in a more compact form (Google Protobuf, [Parquet](https://www.databricks.com/glossary/what-is-parquet), etc.) Reading in that way can be considerably faster, as you're usually just IO bound, not server/CPU bound.

Comment: @tadman Caching would not be practical in this scenario, as the data I am fetching is used immediately and discarded afterwards. Query > Compute Results > Show Results to User > Discard.

Adding an intermediate step to serialize the data to a temporarily file took longer (in my experiments).

Comment: Fair enough. You'll need to dig deeper and find out where the bottlenecks are by measuring this much more carefully.

Comment: If SQL Server is local, you can try running your Python in the SQL Server Python Language Extension, which has special data transfer mechanisms optimized for this scenario. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/concepts/extension-python?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

Pyspark dataframes run faster than pandas dataframes and should provide more memory.
If you already have the dataframe in pandas, you can convert like this:

```
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df) 

modified_df=spark_df.filter("query here").collect()
```

You can convert back to pandas if you need after main sql querying.

link:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html